# Proper way to write and save text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm starting my first project in Python(started two weeks ago).

This is something that I didn't learn on the course and it's not very clear on internet due to many different ways to do it.
This is the bit of code I have written and I need the input to be **saved** in a **text file**, to have the **list** of **names** of the employees.

```
if name.lower() == "add":
        n_input = input("Name:")
        with open('names.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(n_input)
```

When I run this it works perfect, no traceback. But it's **not saving** the input in the list.
I accept critiques, recommendations, changes, etc. As I said I'm new and I only want to learn.

Thank you very much.

FULL CODE BELOW:

```
snames = list()
f_n = (open('names.txt')).read()
#names_f = f_n.read()
print("Welcome to NAME.app")
while True:
    name = input("Please select waiter/tress name - ADD to save new name - LIST to see saved names:")
    #try:

    if name.lower() == "add":
        n_input = input("Name:")
        with open('names.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(n_input)
        continue

    elif name == snames:
        print(name)#doubtful line. print name of list.

    elif name.lower() == "list":
        print(f_n)

    elif name == "exit":
        exit()
```

Comment: Thank you, that answers a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you *write* to a file, you replace everything in that file. If you want to add to the file, use `with open('names.txt', 'a') as f` to append the file.

[How do you append to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python)

I would make sure these were separated by a newline as well:

```
if name.lower() == "add":
        n_input = input("Name:")
        with open('names.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(n_input + "\n")
```

**NOTE:** This example will have an empty last line.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's working now it's adding the names. Any possibility of a way of updating the file info? When I write a name in the file and then I want to check the list in the file I have to exit the code to see the names added. Thank you anyway !!

Comment: @AlejandroTrinchero You should create a new question for that.